# Declare Global Variable inside a Button1_Click

Tags: variables, button, global, declare

I tried to google this abit but I could'nt find anything useful. So I in my form1_load I have this variable

```
Dim Myvariable As String
```

then in a button click I want

```
Myvariable = "Hello"
```

Problem is that my code tells me that Myvariable in the button_click is not declared which it is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the example from @Łukasz Tara doesn't help you (which it should), then please post your code so we can figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move variable as a field or property in Your form class. Here is example code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private MyVariable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MyVariable = "Hello"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox.Show(MyVariable)
    End Sub
End Class
```